# Spring boot unit test not not working while returning hard coded values

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito, spring-test

I have below REST endpoint mapping.

```
@GetMapping("/employee/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<Employee> getEmployee(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
    Employee employee = employeeRepository.getEmployeeById (id);
    if(employee == null) {
        throw new EmployeeNotFoundException ();
    }
    ResponseEntity<Employee> responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<Employee> (employee, HttpStatus.OK);
    return responseEntity;
}
```

To test the failing path, I have the following test case.

```
@Test
public void getEmployeeFailTest() throws Exception {
    Mockito.when (employeeRepository.getEmployeeById (Mockito.anyInt ())).thenReturn (null);
    RequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get ("/employee/10")
            .accept (MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform (requestBuilder).andReturn ();
    String response = result.getResponse ().getContentAsString ();
    System.out.println (employeeRepository.getEmployeeById (5)==null);
    String expected = "{\"errorCode\":1,\"message\":\"404: Employee not found!\"}";
    JSONAssert.assertEquals (expected, response, false);
    Assert.assertEquals (404, result.getResponse ().getStatus ());
}
```

In the repository class, I am returning the hardcoded Employee object.

```
public Employee getEmployeeById(int i) {
    Employee employeeMock = new Employee (1, "XYZ","randomEmail@gmail.com",new Department (1, "HR"));
    return  employeeMock;
}
```

The test cases are passing successfully when I return `null` in the above method. But with the above implementation, it fails.

Thanks to `Mockito.when (employeeRepository.getEmployeeById (Mockito.anyInt ())).thenReturn (null);`  `getEmployeeById` is returning `null` in test method but in controller's method above hardcoded `Employee` object is getting returned

Am I missing something?

Comment: show how you declare the the repository. Also just to be clear.. you expect null but you get a hardcoded value right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) If I understand your test correctly then you expect "404 not found" in response to "employee/10". When you return `null` then REST controller throws `EmployeeNotFoundException` (which I assume handled via exception handler and converted to 404). When you return non-null object then exception is not thrown and test fails.

I suggest your repository class emulates object not found by

```
public Employee getEmployeeById(int i) {
  return i==10 ? null : new Employee (1, "XYZ","randomEmail@gmail.com",new Department (1, "HR"));
}
```

2) `Mockito.when (employeeRepository.getEmployeeById (Mockito.anyInt ())).thenReturn (null);` this code does not seem working. I assume you do not inject `employeeRepository` to REST properly. You should mark  it with `@MockBean` in your test class so Spring Test will prefer it over real implementation

Comment: @Mock does not inject anything, it is pretty useless annotation.  All it does is invoking  Mockito.create and assigning to the field. Real implementation is injected by Spring because there is no other candidates.

Answer (score 0):

Your employeeRepository instance in the REST controller is probably not the same instance you are trying to stub the return value of in your test.

A mock instance would normally return null by default for most reference types. Since you are getting the hardcoded object, it looks like your concrete implementation is being used in the REST controller.
Assuming your REST controller gets the employeeRepository through some kind of dependency injection, you need to make sure your mock is injected into it, either by explicitly injecting it or by providing a mock bean for your test's Spring Context.